# Integrate Jquery in Selenium

Tags: jquery, performance, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am thinking to integrate Jquery in Selenium, but I have few questions before applying this to my project and to present and convince my team to use jquery integration, since I know jquery is too powerful (they don't).

1. Since, Selenium is opensource why selenium has not yet integrated Jquery?
2. Advantages of Jquery over Xpath, since CSS has limitations of only traversing top to bottom, Jquery doesn't which is XPath's biggest strength over CSS.
3. Performance Issues after injecting Javascript vs directly using XPath?

And , any other additional advantages of integrating jquery?

Looking for great suggestions and answers.

Regards

Comment: Please make sure to ask single concrete question per post and avoid open-ended discussions like "list other advantages" or "why project X does not use project Y".

Comment: People are way too knowledgeable here, thought they'd know everything